# Automatically select save in dialog box c#

Tags: c#, regex, dialog

I am building an application in C# that opens a link to a `.jpg` using the web browser (to download it).

Some browsers will automatically download and with some others a dialog box will open. On the default `webBrowser1` it shows a dialog box <kbd>open</kbd> <kbd>save</kbd> <kbd>cancel</kbd>. Is there a way for my application to automatically select <kbd>save</kbd>?

---

### Read on for more info on the project:

I have 3 web browsers within a form.

**webBrowser1** opens a page on form load and has a button which:

- Searches for specific links on page using regex. And then saves them
  to a public static array => `links[]`.
- Opens webBrowser2
- Hides the button
- Hides webBrowser1

**webBrowser2**

1. On load opens the first link => `links[0]`
2. On webBrowser2 load checks if it contains regex2
3. If true find another link (the `.jpg` link) with regex3 => `second_links[]` (can only have none or 1)

   - If no link returns to step 1
4. Opens link `second_links[0]` in **webBrowser3**. (This bit can cause errors because it then goes back to step 1 before webBrowser3 has saved the `.jpg`. Any ideas on how to to get around that?)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a browser and not the HttpClient? You would have full control then.

Comment: I am new to c#. Is that a better option?

Comment: A Much better solution.

Comment: @PeterR I meant for a beginner? It looks pretty complicated.

Comment: @PeterR Oh you don't mean do the whole thing using HttpClient? just the download. Get you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, download the file directly.

For example:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var clientResponse = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(imageUri);
```

`clientResponse` is a `byte[]` that would contain the image.

To write to disk:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("path_to_file", FileMode.Create))
{
    fs.Write(clientResponse, 0, clientResponse.Length);
}
```

Comment: Sorry where does the download go? How would you say put it in your Downloads folder?

Comment: You take the bytes, and write them out to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to use the HttpClient to download a jpeg file. Note that this assumes VS2012 and uses async/await. You'll need to reference System.Net.Http in your project for this to build.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace DownloadSample
{
    class Program
    {

        static async void RunClient(string address)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            // Send asynchronous request
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(address);

            // Check that response was successful or throw exception
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Read response asynchronously and save asynchronously to file
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\logo.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string microsoft_logo = "http://c.s-microsoft.com/en-au/CMSImages/mslogo.png?version=856673f8-e6be-0476-6669-d5bf2300391d";
            RunClient(microsoft_logo); //"http://some.domain.com/resource/file.jpg");

            Console.WriteLine("Check download folder");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following for simplicity:

```
var filename = @"C:\image.png";
var url = @"http://www.somedomain.com/image.png";

using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(url, filename);
}

using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename))
{
    // Do something with image.
}
```